# Python Loader using turtle

Tags: python, loading, turtle-graphics

I want to make a loader, like this one:

[image: Loader]

This is my code so far:

```
import turtle, random                # random for colour choice, turtle for design
turtle.hideturtle()                  # don't show arrow

turtle.pensize(10)                   # thick pen
turtle.colormode(255)                # RGB colour format
x = 0                                # loop
while (x < 10):                      # loop
    x = x + 1                        # loop 
    r = random.randint(0,255)        # choose random r
    g = random.randint(0,255)        # choose random g
    b = random.randint(0,255)        # choose random b
    turtle.color((r,g,b))            # new colour every loop
    turtle.circle(100)               # draw circle
```

How can I use python and turtle to make it similar to the one above? I know this question is not very good, but I couldn't find anything on the internet elsewhere about this. I don't want to insert an image into Turtle. I want to create it graphically.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My compromise between your code and your example.  The idea behind it is that it's faster and simpler to spin a custom turtle cursor using timer events than to try to draw something:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

STEP = -12  # should be divisor of 360
GAP = 45  # in degrees
PEN_SIZE = 4  # emulated pen width
RADIUS = 24

def await_loading(degrees=[0], color=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]):  # intentionally dangerous default values

    if degrees[0] == 0:
        color.append(color.pop(0))
        loading.color(color)

    loading.tilt(STEP)

    degrees[0] = (degrees[0] + STEP) % 360

    screen.ontimer(await_loading, 10)

loading = Turtle()
loading.speed('fastest')
loading.backward(RADIUS)
loading.right(90)

loading.begin_poly()
loading.circle(RADIUS, 360 - GAP, 60)
loading.left(90)
loading.forward(PEN_SIZE)
loading.right(90)
loading.circle(RADIUS - PEN_SIZE, GAP - 360, 60)
loading.end_poly()

screen = Screen()
screen.addshape('loading', loading.get_poly())

loading.reset()
loading.shape('loading')

await_loading()

screen.exitonclick()
```

I didn't package it up neatly into a function as I don't know what kind of event will start and stop it -- I just wanted to show the graphics are possible.